# Vertically aligned h1 with div underneath

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get an affect where I have one div that is both vertically and horizontally centered (inside a containing dynamic div). I can achieve this with the following css:

```
#centered-div {
vertical-align: middle;
margin: auto;
}
```

However, I also want another div (also in the parent div) that is horizontally centered AND is always a fixed distance (like 30px) underneath the `#centered-div`.

[image: An image of my desired result]

In the picture the large div is centered both horizontally and vertically relative to the parent container, and the smaller div is directly under the large one. As of right now I haven't found a good way to do this. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? It's hard to picture what you want without more code, or an image. **Note:** I am using `flex` and while its support is growing, it is still relatively new.

```css
#dynamic-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

#centered-div {
  background: red;
  align-self: center;
}

#inside-above-div {
  background: yellow;
}

#inside-below-div {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic-div">

  <!-- This div hold the content -->
  <div id="centered-div">

    <div id="inside-above-div">
      Heading
    </div>

    <div id="inside-below-div">
      paragraph
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of an image. I'll update my question with an image. However, you are striking pretty close, and I think that your answer is good enough. This is simpler and achieves virtually the same thing. :)